# Select from table where the date is later then today

Tags: php, mysql, date

So I'm busy on a schedule system, and since my client works in the tech business, I wanted to make a table listing 5 upcoming productions, based on the date.

The initial way was kinda stupid:

`$date = date('d-m-Y');
SELECT id, name, date, location FROM productions WHERE date = > :date`

As said, pretty stupid, then on stackoverflow, I found a piece of code that made sense to me:

`SELECT id, name, date, location FROM productions WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE LIMIT 5 ORDER BY date`

But as soon as I tried that, the following error popped up:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date' at line 1' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\public\planning.tpl:341 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\public\planning.tpl(341): PDO->prepare('SELECT id, name...') #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.template.php(61): include('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #2 C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.template.php(70): Template->getPage('planning') #3 C:\xampp2\htdocs\index.php(8): Template->render('planning') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\public\planning.tpl on line 341
```

So how do I do this? I've asked several people, and they all don't know..

So how do I select values from a table where the date is later then today?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't LIMIT be the last parameter? Or at least after the ORDER BY statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, `date`, location FROM productions 
    WHERE date(`date`) >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY date(`date`) LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Newbish question: In what format does this get the time?

Comment: take a look on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` goes before `LIMIT`

Check the whole syntax here: [MySQL Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)